# Simple HTML5 validation fails

Tags: html

I am very confused about NU HTML checker at https://validator.w3.org. It is giving me errors despite an obviously simple example. I included doctype, character encoding, and head elements. So why the errors?

Here is my test code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>
Content of the document......
</body>
</html>
```

And my errors...

1. The character encoding was not declared. Proceeding using windows-1252.
2. Start tag seen without seeing a doctype first. Expected e.g. `<!DOCTYPE html>`.
3. Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.

Comment: No repro for me with the linked validator "Document checking completed. No errors or warnings to show."

Comment: Like  Ferrybig said, the part you've posted validates just fine.  There's something you're not showing us.  SUGGESTION: Copy/paste your HTML into the "validate text" tab.  It should validate.  Then determine what's DIFFERENT from what's failing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback The validation works only when I use TEXT and paste my code in, regardless of the type of quote used. If I create a file with the exact same code, upload and validate by URL I get the errors. I also made the quote changes  suggested by Vykintas, but I still get errors when validating by URL. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

**You have a problem width quotes.**

Looks like PHP part interprets your charset declaration as end of HTML, because of wrong quotes type.

You can fix it by replacing

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

width

```
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
```

**OR**
Changing quotes in PHP. For example: from

```
echo "...";
```

to

```
echo'';
```